Filter out getByText elements that contain "disabled" class name
Have a calendar that might have a date displayed twice: from the previous month and for the current month:

The disabled dates have disabled in the class, like this:
<div role="gridcell" class="ngb-dp-day disabled" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Sunday, July 28, 2024">
<span _ngcontent-dug-c147="" class="custom-day weekend disabled"> 28 </span>
<!----><!---->
</div>

The active element does not have disabled in the class name
<div role="gridcell" class="ngb-dp-day" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Wednesday, August 28, 2024">
<span _ngcontent-dug-c147="" class="custom-day"> 28 </span>
<!----><!---->
</div>

In my current implementation I am using page.getByText("28", { exact: true }).click() but it fails because there are two elements with the same text.
How can I filter out the disabled one?
I was trying to use this, but it does not exactly work
await this.page.getByText("28")
    .filter({ hasNot: this.page.locator('span[class~="disabled"]').click()


Please share the page you're automating and a [mcve] of the code you're using to automate it. If I can't run the code and see the page, it's very difficult for me to help. Thanks!

@ggorlen I can't share the page because it's an internal product, I am sorry.

Makes sense, but maybe you could strip out the component you're using and make it reproducible that way, assuming the rest of the page's behavior isn't unexpected.

Thank you @graham-judd for pointing to the correct answer
page.locator("span:not(.disabled)").getByText("28", { exact: true })


Also note the aria-label gives greater specificity than the text.

await page.locator("span.disabled").getByText("28", { exact: true }).click()


I guess I was not clear,  I need the exact opposite. Your solution tries to click on the disabled 28, but I need to filter the disabled element out and click on the one, that DOES NOT have disabled

Add :not(.disabled) - await page.locator("span:not(.disabled)").getByText("28", { exact: true }) returns just the one element.

ok. lets say the answer is: use "locator". You can put there any css selector and find what you need.
